# How to create a closure to return which one of the parameters is true?

Tags: swift

I need to create some sort of closure to return back if it's an optional or forced update. I've created some pseudo code:

```
func verifyAppVersionWithServer(isForceUpdate: bool -> true, isOptionalUpdate: bool -> true) {
   //Some check will be performed here then:
    if isForceUpdate {
        return isForceUpdate -> true
    } else {
        return isOptionalUpdate -> true
    }       
}
```

I'm not sure how to create a closure in Swift which will then return which of the parameters is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably nicer to return an `enum` that indicates the type of update required.

You would then have something like this:

```
enum UpdateType {
    case None
    case Optional
    case Required
}

func verifyAppVersionWithServer(completion:(UpdateType) -> Void) {

    let anyUpdate = true
    let forcedUpdate = false

    if anyUpdate {
        if forcedUpdate {
            completion(.Required)
        } else {
            completion(.Optional)
        }
    } else {
        completion(.None)
    }
}
```

You would call it as:

```
verifyAppVersionWithServer { (updateType) in
    print("Update type is \(updateType)")
}
```

Obviously the values would be determined by your server response, not fixed values as I have shown.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I implemented this but get a compiler error in trying to call it that states `Command failed due to segmentation fault 11`. Would you know why this is?

Comment: I am not sure without additional information about how you are calling and which line caused the exception.  My code works in a playground.

Comment: Your code worked. The mistake was on my end. Tried calling a `class func` using a `func` which would cause it to fail.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like below

```
func verifyAppVersionWithServer(parm1: String, withParma2: Bool, completionHandeler: (isSucess: Bool, error : NSError) -> Void) {

    //Write your logic

    //call complition handeler
    completionHandeler(isSucess: true, error: error)
}
```

Hope this will help